# Call function after time delay and then faster

Tags: javascript, setinterval

I know about `setInterval( foo, n)` that it calls `foo` every `n` seconds.
But how can I do to call it faster and faster? Like after the first time, the function will be called again in `n-1` seconds, then `n-2` seconds, and so on.

Comment: Use `setTimeout` instead because it fires a single time, then you can recalculate the timeout and set the next one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `setTimeout` instead. It will call a function with the new timeout, which will be the previous one -x ms, and so on.
I've added a stop condition, so it won't run forever.

```js
function recall(n) {
  console.log(n);
  
  n -= 100;
  
  n < 0 || setTimeout(function() {
    recall(n);
  }, n);
}

recall(1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

In that case you can use `setTimout` recursively:

```js
function foo () {
   console.log(new Date());
}

function fasterAndFaster(fn, seconds) {
  if (seconds <= 0) { return; }
  setTimeout(function () {
    fn();
    // Recursive call
    fasterAndFaster(fn, seconds - 1);
  }, seconds * 1000);
}

fasterAndFaster(foo, 5);
console.log("Wait 5 seconds");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setTimeout(foo, n)` in combination with `foo.bind` instead, and then recursively call your function.

[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/7ghd692w/)